# Will Dragon Naturally Speaking work in a Windows 7 VM running in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualization

About the only Windows app I want is Dragon Naturally Speaking.

I know people have had some (partial?) success - at least with older versions running under wine, but I would like to get the full product running in a Windows 7 vm - probably using VirtualBox.

I am currently running kubuntu precise with lots of backports, but could upgrade if that would help.

Can this be done?

I am also open to any other approach that will yield a stable working solution.